# how to design database for binary tree?

Tags: database-design

I'm doing a project in the field of multilevel marketing on .Net and SQL server. 
In the database it should save like a binary tree. How should i design a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 has a built-in data-type called **[hierarchyid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx)** to store hierarchical information. Here are some pointers.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/manisblog/archive/2007/08/17/sql-server-2008-hierarchyid.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx

And of course you can do this as mentioned by [arsenmkrt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87053/arsenmkrt) in databases other than sqlserver2008.

Answer (score 4):

```
id | parentid | name
---------------------
 1 | null     | node1
 2 | 1        | node2
 3 | 1        | node3
```

Comment: Exercise: Write a query that returns all decedents from node1.

Comment: you mean this? select * 
From tab where parentid = (select id from table where name = 'node1')

Comment: That's hilarious :-) However, you probably should have pointed out a better alternative, like using nested sets model.

Comment: To **Arsenmkrt** - no, that would be direct descendants. You were asked for all descendants :)

Comment: @ChssPly76 well, that's easy no? select * from tab where name != 'node1' ;) but seriously how does this answer have 3 upvotes?

Answer (score 4):

This has been [asked and answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935098/database-structure-for-tree-data-structure).

Here's a [pretty decent tutorial](http://sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database) which explains why adjacency model proposed by **arsenmkrt** is less than ideal.

Comment: +1 I didn't think about that before ;)