# help with tree-like structure

Tags: sql, database-design, data-structures, tree

I've got some financial data to store and manipulate. Let's say I have 2 divisions, with offices in 2 cities, in 2 currencies, and 4 bank accounts. (It's actually more complex than that.) I want to show a list like this:

```
Electronics
    Chicago
        Dollars
            Account 2 -> transactions in acct2 in $ in chicago/electronics
        Euros
            Account 1 -> transactions in acct1 in E in chicago/electronics
            Account 3 -> etc.
            Account 4
    Brussles
        Dollars
            Account 1
        Euros
            Account 3
            Account 4
Dessert Toppings
    Chicago
        Dollars
            Account 1
            Account 4
        Euros
            Account 2
            Account 4
    Brussles
        Dollars
            Account 2
        Euros
            Account 3
            Account 4
```

So at each level except the top, the category can appear in multiple places. I've been [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935098/database-structure-for-tree-data-structure) [around](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/) about the various methods, but none of the examples seem to address my particular use case, where nodes can appear in more than one place in the hierarchy. (Maybe there's a different name for this than "tree" or "hierarchy".)

I guess my hierarchy is actually something like Division > City > Currency with 'Electronics' and 'Euros' merely instances of each level, but I'm not quite sure how that helps or hurts.

**A few notes**: this is for a demo site, so the dataset won't be large -- ease of set-up and maintenance is more important than query efficiency. (I'm actually considering just building a data object by hand, though I'd much rather do it the *right way*.) Also, FWIW, we're working in php with an ms access back-end, so any libraries out there that make this easy in that environment would be helpful. (I've found a couple of implementations of the nested set pattern already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use a hierarchical design for this? To me, the hierarchy seems more a consequence of the desired output format than something intrinsic to your data structure.

And what if you have to display the data in a different order, like City > Currency > Division? Wouldn't that be very cumbersome?

You could use a plain structure instead, with a table for Branches, one for Cities, one for Currencies, and then then one Account table with Branch_ID, City_ID, and Currency_ID as foreign keys.

Comment: That's the conclusion that I came to, as well, at least for these fields. There's a vague request for "arbitrary nested groups", but I'll have to get more details on what that really means before deciding how to implement them...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what database platform you're using.  But if you're using **MS SQL Server**, then you should check out **recursive queries using common table expressions** (CTEs).  They're easy to use and are designed for exactly the type of situation you've illustrated (a bill of materials, for instance).  Check out this website for more detail:  http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1520

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, we're using MS Access.