# Tree structure in sqlite for iphone

Tags: sql, ios, cocoa-touch

I was looking to make a tree structure in sqlite DB.

I have gone through this link   [Database Structure for Tree Data Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935098/database-structure-for-tree-data-structure)

Currently My TREE is maintained using NSMutableDictonary and stored in plist.
I wanted to store it in DB instead of plist.

Any hint in the direction would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a table of (parent, child) that will hold the connection between the nodes.
The Nodes themselves will have to be in a different table.

Comment: can you direct me to some tutorial or quick reference ?