# Rails 3.1 How to recursively count threads belonging to a chain of forums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Forum::Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_forum, :class_name => "Forum"
  has_many :sub_forums, :class_name => "Forum", :foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_many :threads

  def count_threads
    threads.count
  end
end
```

Hi I am trying to count all the threads that belong to a forum right though the chain.
Currently it counts the threads that belong to the forum you're on, so if you're on forum id 1 it will count threads that belong to forum id 1 only, however forum id 1 also has sub_forums such as forum id 4 which also has a sub_forum with a id of 8 and this could go on forever.

I would really appreciate some help here, I have grand plans to build my site in rails instead of zend framework but a few little snags are keeping me stuck sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look at [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry).   You should be able to get everything you need out of there if your model is what I think it is, and it can save you some code.

I believe something like `@record.descendants.count` should do the trick once you've integrated it.

Comment: I wish to stick to a vanilla rails solution.

Comment: In that case I believe you're going to need to recurs through your associations in order to find all children/children of children/etc.  I haven't read it in depth, but this may give you some ideas for more efficient layout of your tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935098/database-structure-for-tree-data-structure