# SQL Server statement to get children using parent id - refactor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `content_folder_tbl` that has a list of all folders and sub folders defined with `folder_id` and `parent_id`

I want to get all the folders id once I define the root `folder_id`.

As a workaround I came up with this query :

```
 select * 
 from content_folder_tbl 
 where folder_id in (select folder_id 
                     from content_folder_tbl 
                     where parent_id = 73 
                     UNION
                     Select folder_id 
                     from content_folder_tbl 
                     where parent_id in (select folder_id 
                                         from content_folder_tbl 
                                         where parent_id = 73)
                     Union
                     Select folder_id 
                     from content_folder_tbl 
                     where parent_id in (Select folder_id 
                                         from content_folder_tbl 
                                         where parent_id in (select folder_id
                                                             from content_folder_tbl 
                                                             where parent_id = 73))
  )
```

It returns exactly what I want, but it's redundant and works only if I have 3 levels folders.

How to rewrite this query to return values for any level (looks like I need a recursive approach)?

`73` is the root `folder_id` in this case

Example of expected result:

[image]

Comment: Yes a recursive cte is what you need here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10369684/5309594

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tree structure data query in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369634/tree-structure-data-query-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one -

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.content_folder_tbl
    WHERE folder_id = 73

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t2.*
    FROM cte t1
    JOIN dbo.content_folder_tbl t2 ON t1.folder_id = t2.parent_id
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: returns more values than expected, but looks like a good base for me

Comment: please provide a small example with expected result

Comment: please check a query. sorry :) don't have a crystal ball

Comment: i posted the right expected result now. sorry about that

Comment: Yes that was the right one . answer accepted. the only missing thing is that it includes the root folder_id, but i can fix that

Comment: great. have a nice day :)